# Nginx: How to rewrite only when all location blocks fail?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a web site which needs to be using https connection for pretty much the whole site except a few locations which I need to be served via http. To do that I have two servers setup in nginx config. One is for non-secure and one for secure connections. However for the non-secure server, I want to be able to rewrite to the secure web one only when none of the location blocks are validated.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Structure of my nginx config:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   ...
   location /foo1 { ... }
   location /foo2 { ... }
   # i can't get this rewrite to work only when all location blocks fail
   rewrite ^/(.*) https://foo.com/$1 permanent;
}
server {
   listen 443;
   ...
}
```

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the end of the `server` block:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://foo.com/$1 permanent;
}
```